# How to cast TransitionDrawable to BitmapDrawable?

Tags: android, android-glide, android-photoview

I have use [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) libraries for my android project.
The app is fetching images from a url and display them in a GridView. When the user clicks on a image it gets loaded into photoview which is inside a fragment of same activity.

Now i want to set that image as a wallpaper so I have written the following inside the button click listener:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity());
bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) photoView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
try{
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error is in the following line:

`bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) photoView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

Error is: Cannot cast TransitionDrawable into BitmapDrawable

How to cast it?
or
Is there any other way to set wallpaper?

Answer (score 0):

```
    ImageVIEW.setImageBitmap( getUri( Uri.parse( blob ) ) );


private Bitmap getUri(Uri uri) {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = null;
    try {
        parcelFileDescriptor = activity.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor( uri, "r" );
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor( fileDescriptor );
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e( TAG, "Failed to load image.", e );
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
                parcelFileDescriptor.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e( TAG, "Error closing ParcelFile Descriptor" );
        }
    }
```

**[all details in this link](https://github.com/andrewemadgabra/InventoryApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/andrew/inventoryapp/InventoryAdapter.java)**

Comment: Hey Andrew could be please explain this....as far as i understand is that it will set image to an ImageView using a Uri.

I want to get the image from the PhotoView using getBitmap()...how to use this code?

Comment: you see the link click in word All details in this link